# MS Excel 2007 not displaying chart as required

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have **Category Names** to select from cells A3, A5, A7, & **Values** from E3, E5, E7. The slices on the pie chart show as appropriate, if I omit the Category Names; but do not, if I include them in my cell selection for chart creation.

How do I get the pie chart to work correctly, and show the category names?

Erroneous pie-chart after all the aformentioned cells selections:
[image: Erroneous pie-chart after all the aformentioned cells selection]

Correct pie-chart after partial cell-selection:
[image: Correct pie-chart after partial cell-selection]

Addendum: I am familiar that the feature **Select Data Source** can assist me with the inclusion of Category Names in the chart. So, their addition is not as much of a problem as the bug that this particular PC may have with its Excel application, as I've seen the same working on other PCs.

Thank you for indulging!

Comment: Can you post images of both scenarios please?